# Issue implementing gradle multi-project with dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

I've got a gradle project that contains my `app` and then my `lib`. I'm seeing errors when trying to build my `app` module because it can't find the dependencies needed by the `lib` module.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2.
Searched in the following locations:
  file:/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.4.2/play-services-location-11.4.2.pom
  file:/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.4.2/play-services-location-11.4.2.jar
  file:/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.4.2/play-services-location-11.4.2.pom
  file:/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.4.2/play-services-location-11.4.2.jar
  file:/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.4.2/play-services-location-11.4.2.pom
  file:/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.4.2/play-services-location-11.4.2.jar

Required by:
  project :app > project :lib
```

This error is duplicative for all of the `lib` module's dependencies. I currently have these dependencies defined in `lib/build.gradle` under the repositories.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2'
    // ...
}
// ...
```

When I run `./gradlew lib:assembleDebug` I get a success message that the lib has built. So I know that the repositories/dependencies definitions are correct for that module. Unfortunately building the app doesn't get the desired results:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug --rerun-tasks --console plain
:buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy
:buildSrc:processResources NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:classes
:buildSrc:jar
:buildSrc:assemble
:buildSrc:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:test NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:build
The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead.
:app:customTask
:app:preBuild
:lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:checkDebugManifest
:lib:processDebugManifest
:app:preDebugBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2.
// ...
```

I do have some tasks in the app module that I inject before the preBuild task. I don't think this is causing things to be thrown off but I'll mention it just in case.

If anyone has any suggestions on implementing a multi-project gradle app where a subproject defines its own repositories I'd be very thankful.

Comment: try to use api instead of implementation in your project for importing your lib

Comment: After reading the docs it I think I'm supposed to be using api for this instead of implementation, unfortunately it doesn't seem to change the error.

Comment: I've crossposted this issue on the gradle forums with a sample project that exemplifies the behavior.   https://discuss.gradle.org/t/project-requires-same-repositories-defined-as-library-module/25145